# compiling an Eclipse project into a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jar

I reference another eclipse project from the current project I am working on.

Everything is working fine except when I try to jar up the referenced project and use the jar instead of the eclipse project my project doesn't run properly.

I know this is a bit vague but is there something I might be doing wrong in jaring up the referenced eclipse project that eclipse takes care of when I just add the project as a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.

The Project I was referencing has a set of reference libraries, which when I referenced the project were added as references to my project, however when I compiled the project to a jar, those projects were no longer referenced by my project so it didn't work

The solution was to add the referenced projects to the references of my project.